# Fixtures with picklefield library for Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, pickle, fixtures

A straight forward question:

Is there some easy way to write fixtures (i.e. in JSON format, but I don't care really) when using models that incorporate `PickleFields`?

**EDIT:**

In the end I think I'll just get rid of fixtures altogether. I'll use named *.py scripts that will create all the objects for me. I've always found fixtures quite cumbersome anyway.

Comment: Perhaps use the Python interactive terminal to `pickle` the object that you'd like, and copy and paste? (I'm adding this as a comment and not an answer because I'm not sure if it will really fit your particular needs).

Comment: @Luke Well, that's the least I can do, however I'm still hoping for some easier way around that. Probably would also have to take care of some heavy escaping though...

Comment: That's a valid point. Honestly, `./manage.py dumpdata` is probably your best bet, all things considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using [django-picklefield](https://github.com/shrubberysoft/django-picklefield) you can use [dumpdata](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model)/loaddata just like you would with any other model. Tested it briefly and everything works fine.

Comment: Yea, it turns out that binary data is written using base64 encoding, so it's indeed possible to use dumpdata, however I probably will use another solution described in the EDIT.